# Allowing users to remotely connect to mysql db

Tags: c#, mysql, whitelist, remote-connection

First of all, I took a look to every related topic on her about this issue. However non of them was successful in answering my question fully.

Curently I am working on a desktop app, coded in C#, that requires mysql connection both for authentication and storing user custom lists etc.

I put my test database in my account on hostgator and I connected to it with a connection string that looks like;

```
public static string cs = "Server=xx.xx.xxx.xx;Port=3306;Database=xxx;Uid=xx;Password=xxx";
```

Even though everything was 100% correct, the connection wasn't possible until I whitelisted my own ip address.

Now everything is working perfect for me, however the thing is that how am I supposed to whitelist all the users of my desktop app for them to be able to connect to the db.

Is there anything that I can do to allow the connection without having to whitelist everyone?

Thank you in advance
Alex

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that'll probably an MySQL (or perhaps even a firewall) configuration option. I guess though that the hoster doesn't allow everyone to connect to a hosted MySQL service, because of the obvious security concerns.

You'd better write a simple service that runs on the webserver, which will publish the data you wish to share. You can then consume this service in your C# app.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, actually that was the first thing came to my mind as well. However, I thought about it a lot and couldn't come up with a bright idea. I tried to write a simple script in php that will run my desired SQL queries on my mysql database but couldn't figure out the right way to send and receive information from the script. 

Any ideas? 

Thanks

Comment: @Alex I didn't mean in the style of a service that executes SQL commands from the client app, but about creating for example a [SOAP server](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapserver.php) which translates SOAP method calls to results from the database. Those results can be (strong-typedly) read back into your application, enabling you to directly work with them as objects in code. I guess this means quite a rewrite, but enabling anyone to connect to a MySQL server (and any SQL server really) is generally a bad idea.

Comment: I see what you are saying and it sounds like a good idea. However, I had no idea that it was bad practice to allow every user to connect to the MySQL database. But I guess the reason for that is pretty much about SQL injections and stuff. However, if you can suggest me another way or ways of authenticating users and storing/loading user data to/from a MySQL database in case of a desktop app, I'll be glad. It's my first time that I am using MySQL db with a desktop app   and not with a local php script. Thank you.